# Calling a method from another .java file in order to modify an object

Tags: java

I'm trying to do two separate things here: First, I need to do a call similar to p.addTechnologies in order to add the "technologies" (programming languages) to each programmer object. Then I need to use the getSalary() method in Programmer in order to set the new salary of the programmer, based on how many languages he/she knows.

Currently when compiled and ran, it produces the correct output, except it doesn't put the technologies in and doesn't change the salary of the programmers.

Programmer Donald Ervin Knuth with SSN 444-44-4444 has salary $75,000.00 and knows Assembly and C

Above is an example of what needs to be printed out. Below is what I have so far:

Programmer Donald Ervin Knuth with SSN 444-44-4444 has salary $65,000.00

**EDIT** I have removed unnecessary parts of the code for this question for Dr. Ward as I'm sure he does not want his students to simply copy and paste this. **END EDIT**

```
public class ReadEmployees {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException 
    {
        /* Defined my variables here */

        // This block reads in input from a file
        try 
        {
            //This block creates a file object, creates a scanner and creates a linereader. 
            File file = new File(fileName); //Creates file object
            Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file) ; //Creates scanner object to read file

            //While there is a next line in the file, read in the next line.
            while (scanner.hasNextLine() )
            {
                /* I split into input string here */

                if (jobDescription.equalsIgnoreCase("Employee"))
                {
                Employee e = new Employee(name, ssn);
                Employee.add(e);
                System.out.println(e.toString());
                }
                if (jobDescription.equalsIgnoreCase("Clerical worker"))
                {
                    Employee cw = new ClericalWorker(name, ssn);
                    Employee.add(cw);
                    System.out.println(cw.toString());
                }
                if (jobDescription.equalsIgnoreCase("Programmer"))
                {
                    Employee p = new Programmer(name, ssn);
                    System.out.println(p.toString());   
                }
                if (jobDescription.equalsIgnoreCase("Web developer"))
                {
                    Employee wd = new WebDeveloper(name, ssn);
                    System.out.println(wd.toString());
                }
                if (jobDescription.equalsIgnoreCase("Contract programmer"))
                {
                    Employee cp = new ContractProgrammer(name, ssn);
                    System.out.println(cp.toString());
                }
            }
            scanner.close();
        }
        catch (FileNotFoundException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 
    }   
}
```

Comment: post the code that is causing you troubles here, and explain what the problem is.

Comment: It doesn't look like you ever use `tech` (in your file reading code) or call `addTechnologies()` - seems like you need to call that after you create the `Programmer`, or accommodate setting the values in the `Programmer` or `Employee` constructor.

Comment: Problem: The programmer object is not having technologies (programming languages added to it) The method I have to do so is addTechnology(String tech) When I try to call p.addTechnology(tech) I get an error that addTechnology is not defined in Employee.java. I've linked my code in a gist because I'm inexperienced in posting code on this site.

Comment: Convenience at its finest: when your professor helps edit your question. Thanks Dr. Ward! 

Also, duh! No wonder I couldn't call p.addTechnology. It would help if I would actually define the object as a programmer >.> Now I need to figure out why tech "is not defined" when I try to call p.addTechnology(tech)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all when you created a `Programmer` you declared p as an `Employee` (the base class). The error you were getting is accurate the Employee class does not have a method `addTechnology`.  You should have declared it as

```
Programmer p = new Programmer(name, ssn);
```

I did not see your input file included but from the parsing I gather it to be formatted like this:

`Programmer:Jeff Ward:444-44-4444:C#:Java:Python`

You would need to change the parsing of the technologies like this:

```
if (details.length > 3) {
    technologies = details[3].split(":");
}
```

Then later in the block for dealing with a Programmer do the following:

```
if (jobDescription.equalsIgnoreCase("Programmer")) {
   // p must be of type Programmer to call addTechnology method
   Programmer p = new Programmer(name, ssn);
   for (String tech : technologies) {
      p.addTechnology(tech);
   }
   System.out.println(p.toString());
}
```

If you make these updates you will see output like this:

`Programmer Jeff Ward with SSN 444-44-4444 has salary $83,000.00 and knows C#, Java, and Python`

**Note:** In the code I provided above I removed your `tech` variable so that I could declare it as the variable for the loop.

Comment: I had just noticed that I had declared p as an employee and immediately felt ridiculous. (It's the little mistakes!)I also managed to get the output to print the technologies, however they still had the colons in-between each language. (Which I assume was preventing my addTechnology method from doing its job.) 
I appreciate all your help Dr. Ward!